# Checking out from github on Windows has strange CRLF effect

Tags: git, github, git-diff, core.autocrlf

I am working on a project on two different Windows systems.

If I keep working on one system, `git diff` will correctly show the differences to the last commit. I commit my changes and push them to github.

But as soon as I want to continue on the other system, after a `git pull origin main` from github, and changing the code, `git diff` shows additional CR characters for line endings that I cannot explain other than `it seems to happen only when github is involved`.

The `core.autocrlf` config settings are false on both systems for the project, the user, and the system config. I use Visual Studio Code on both ends and the CRLF settings are equal in both editors.

What can I do to stop the erroneous behavior of `git diff` in this situation?

Comment: How about using a `.gitattributes` file: 
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings#per-repository-settings

Answer (score 1):

The comment regarding `.gitattributes` was worth its weight in gold :-)

I added the following to `.gitattributes`, committed it, pushed it, pulled it on the other side ... and now both sides no longer show weird `git diff` output

```
* text=auto
*.js text eol=crlf
```